# App Action "open app" with feature parameter sometimes ignores parameter

Tags: android, app-actions

I have been going through the codelab ["Extend an Android app to the Google Assistant with App Actions (Level 2)"](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appactions-2/#0) and am working on the step ["Add the Open app feature BII capability"](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appactions-2/#4) I have added the relevant configurations to the shortcuts.xml file (see below). The following has been tested with both a real device (A Motorola Moto G Power running Android 11 with 3664M of memory) and virtual devices (A Pixel 5 running Android 12 (API 31) that was tested with both 1536MB and 4096MB of memory)

I've confirmed that this works with the App Action test tool.

If I then invoke it from the Assistant, it will start the app and show the correct information based on the feature.

If, however, I then return to the Android home screen and again invoke it from the Assistant, trying out a different feature, it will bring up the app, but often stay on the same information as before. If I make sure to close the app (by swiping it away in the app list), it will always work, but if I just return to the home screen, sometimes it works correctly and sometimes it does not.

Working on a hunch, and having only a tenuous grasp of Android, I suspected that the call to `TasksActivity.onCreate()` wasn't being called because the app hadn't been destroyed. Adding logging for this method, along with `onStart()`, `onResume()`, `onPause()`, and `onStop()` seems to confirm this. From what I can gather, it is in `onCreate()` where it builds the layout that includes the `TasksFragment`.

I can confirm that `TasksFragment.onCreateView()` is being called only when `TasksActivity.onCreate()` is. It seems to use `activity?.intent?.extras` to get the feature parameter.

At the suggestion of some friends who are better Android developers than me, they suggested that I add a `TasksFragment.onResume()` to catch when the view is being re-shown and to use `activity?.intent?.extras` again to et the feature parameter. While I can verify that it is being called when I re-invoke it from the home screen (and when `onCreate()`/`onCreateView()` is not called), it seems to retain the *old* value for "feature" (and, I assume, the entire old Intent).

The question is thus:

- **How can I correctly capture the correct Intent and parameter under all circumstances - both when a "cold start" of an app as well as returning to an app that is already running?**

Should we be doing something in a different part of the lifecycle? Doing work somewhere besides `onCreate()`?

*Portion of log when invoking for the first time using "show my completed tasks using AppName". Note the `onCreateView` and `onCreate` and that `feature=completed_tasks`.*:

```
2022-07-12 20:07:55.912 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksFragment: >> onCreateView
2022-07-12 20:07:55.912 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksFragment: [feature=completed_tasks]
2022-07-12 20:07:55.912 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksFragment: [com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.starter.IntentStarter.ERROR_TOAST_ID=2132082905]
2022-07-12 20:07:55.912 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksFragment: [extra_accl_intent=true]
2022-07-12 20:07:55.987 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksActivity: >> onCreate
2022-07-12 20:07:55.988 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksActivity: [feature=completed_tasks]
2022-07-12 20:07:55.988 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksActivity: [com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.starter.IntentStarter.ERROR_TOAST_ID=2132082905]
2022-07-12 20:07:55.988 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksActivity: [extra_accl_intent=true]
2022-07-12 20:07:56.012 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksActivity: >> onStart
2022-07-12 20:07:56.018 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksActivity: >> onResume
2022-07-12 20:07:56.020 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksFragment: >> onResume
2022-07-12 20:07:56.020 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksFragment: [feature=completed_tasks]
2022-07-12 20:07:56.020 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksFragment: [com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.starter.IntentStarter.ERROR_TOAST_ID=2132082905]
2022-07-12 20:07:56.020 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksFragment: [extra_accl_intent=true]
```

*Portion of log when returning to home screen*:

```
2022-07-12 20:09:20.073 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksActivity: >> onPause
2022-07-12 20:09:20.124 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksActivity: >> onStop
```

*Portion of log when then re-invoking app with "show my open tasks using AppName". Note that `onCreate` and `onCreateView` are **not** logged, and that `feature=completed_tasks` even tho this should be "active_tasks" based on the invocation feature parameter*:

```
2022-07-12 20:09:22.130 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksActivity: >> onStart
2022-07-12 20:09:22.132 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksActivity: >> onResume
2022-07-12 20:09:22.132 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksFragment: >> onResume
2022-07-12 20:09:22.133 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksFragment: [feature=completed_tasks]
2022-07-12 20:09:22.133 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksFragment: [com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.starter.IntentStarter.ERROR_TOAST_ID=2132082905]
2022-07-12 20:09:22.133 18392-18392/com.addventure.appactions.common D/TasksFragment: [extra_accl_intent=true]
```

*Relevant portion of shortcuts.xml file*:

```xml
    <!--    OPEN APP FEATURE with inline inventory
        https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature

        Be sure to replace all occurrences of PUT_YOUR_APPLICATION_ID_HERE with the
        application ID you specified in app/build.gradle.
    -->
    <!-- Add Get Thing BII shortcuts   -->
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="active_tasks"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/label_active"
        android:enabled="false">
        <capability-binding
            android:key="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
            <parameter-binding
                android:key="feature"
                android:value="@array/active_tasks_synonyms" />
        </capability-binding>
    </shortcut>

    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="completed_tasks"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/label_completed"
        android:enabled="false">
        <capability-binding
            android:key="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
            <parameter-binding
                android:key="feature"
                android:value="@array/completed_tasks_synonyms" />
        </capability-binding>
    </shortcut>

    <!-- Add Open App Feature BII capability   -->
    <capability android:name="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.addventure.appactions.common"
            android:targetClass="com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.tasks.TasksActivity">
            <parameter
                android:name="feature"
                android:key="feature"/>
        </intent>
    </capability>
```

*Relevant portion of TasksActivity.kt*:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.tasks_act)
        setupNavigationDrawer()
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

        // Logging for troubleshooting purposes
        log(TAG, "onCreate", intent)

        val navController: NavController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        appBarConfiguration =
            AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.tasks_fragment_dest, R.id.statistics_fragment_dest)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout)
                .build()
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
            .setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        log(TAG, "onStart")
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        log( TAG, "onResume")
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        log( TAG, "onPause" )
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        log( TAG, "onStop" )
    }

    override fun onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy()
        log( TAG, "onDestroy" )
    }

    companion object {
        fun log( tag: String, f: String ){
            log( tag, f, null )
        }

        fun log(tag: String, f: String, intent: Intent?) {
            Log.d(tag, ">> $f")
            val bundle: Bundle = intent?.extras ?: return

            bundle.keySet().forEach { key ->
                Log.d(tag, "[$key=${bundle.get(key)}]");
            }
        }
    }
```

*Relevant portion of TasksFragment.kt*:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        viewDataBinding = TasksFragBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
            viewmodel = viewModel
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        // Set a listener on task button
        setupFab()

        setFiltering( "onCreateView" )

        return viewDataBinding.root
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        setFiltering( "onResume" )
    }

    private fun setFiltering(f: String){
        TasksActivity.log( TAG, f, activity?.intent )
        viewModel.setFiltering(TasksFilterType.find(activity?.intent?.extras?.getString(OPEN_APP_FEATURE)))

        viewModel.setFiltering(activity?.intent?.extras?.getString(GET_THING))
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So one thing to check is [Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack)

You should also check your [Android Manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element) in the `<activity>` tag, you can set the `android:launchMode` attribute to something like

```kotlin
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

This will force [Activity.onNewIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) to be called when the app is started with a new intent. In this method, you can call [Activity.setIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setIntent(android.content.Intent)) with the new Intent that is passed so it has the correct Intent set when it resumes.

In the *TasksActivity.kt* file, it might look like this:

```kotlin
    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        log(TAG, "onNewIntent", intent)
        setIntent( intent )
    }
```